# C++ Windows API return 1L; в WM_ERASEBKGND

Tags: c++, winapi

```
case WM_ERASEBKGND: {
  RECT rc;
  hdc = (HDC)wParam;
  GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
  SetMapMode(hdc, MM_ANISOTROPIC);
  SetWindowExtEx(hdc, 100, 100, NULL);
  SetViewportExtEx(hdc, rc.right, rc.bottom, NULL);
  FillRect(hdc, &rc, CreateSolidBrush(this->background));
  return 1L;
}
```

Что происходит когда return 1L?

Мой метод который обновляет background не работает если заменить return 1L; на break;

```
bool Window::SetBackground(COLORREF background) {
  this->background = background;
  InvalidateRect(this->hwnd, NULL, TRUE);
  return true;
}
```

Что такое 1L? в чем разница между return 1L; и break;?

Comment: `1L` - это целочисленный литерал для типа `long`, a `break` относится к `switch`

Comment: @VTT return 1L; значит вернуть 1 (long)?

Comment: @VTT а почему метод работает только при return 1L? а при break нет?

Comment: Потому что возврат из функции происходит посредством использования `return`, а `break` работает внутри `switch`

Comment: @VTT понял, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разница между 1L и break действительно существует, но в вашем случае важнее что происходит после break. Поскольку обработчик `WM_ERASEBKGND` может возвращать либо `FALSE`, либо `TRUE` (что в случае С/С++ означает либо 0, либо ненулевое значение), то очевидно, что после break у вас стоит `return 0`.

Конкретно `return 1L` сообщает системе, что ваш обработчик это сообщение обработал (стер фон) и система стирать ничего не должна. Если вы ставите `break` (то есть выполняете `return 0`), то вы говорите системе, что ваш обработчик не стал обрабатывать это сообщение, и его должна обработать система (другими словами, стереть все сама - при этом, вероятно, удалив результат вашего обработчика).